# Simulate is meant to be run on 1 node = 0 found : Jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Here is the method. Trying to test without using spy functions

```js
  removeParameters(id) {
    delete this.state.dataSetList[id];
    this.setState({
      dataSetList: this.state.dataSetList
    });
    this.props.addDataSetList({ dataSetList: this.state.dataSetList });
  }
```

Here is what I have for my test so far:

```js
it(' removeParameters : should return DefaultData props correct', () => {
  baseProps.addDataSetList.mockClear();
  wrapper.setState({
    dataSetList: []
  });
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('dataSetList').simulate('remove', [{ id: { id: 'test1' } }]);
  expect(wrapper.instance().removeParameters('test')).toEqual();
  expect(baseProps.addDataSetList).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: I can't see any code where you are attempting to call `simulate`. Have you included the right test?

Comment: @Matt I'm not really sure how to approach the problem - I am familiar with props and clicks so far

Comment: Usually this error happens when you try to do something like `wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')` and jest cannot find a button. You must have a line of code in one of your tests where you are attempting to call `simulate`.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example based on what I wrote - I added a simulate statement on but it does not look right

Comment: Your find can only use certain selectors, they're CSS-style selectors such as `#id`, `.class` or `element`. Have a look at the [Enzyme documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html)

Comment: That's what I have used to onclicks and onchange events - how could I test the method above for example

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're testing form the code you have shared.

Comment: Trying to find out and test method: removeparements -  first few lines of code

Comment: I really don't think you are using Enzyme correctly here. You need to declare wrapper by calling shallow or mount and passing a React component like this `const wrapper = shallow(<Component />)`. If you just want to test a function in isolation then Jest is enough, you would do something like `expect (removeParameters('<testId>')).toEqual(<expectedResult>)`. Sorry I can't be of further help.

Comment: I already declared the component, I just didn't include here